# Github Pages with Route 53 is giving an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, github-pages, amazon-route53

I am getting this error from Github:

Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, servicelead.com, that's set up with an AAAA record. GitHub Pages currently does not support IPv6. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/.

And this is the dns records I have set:

[image]

I can't figure out where I am going wrong.  It does not look like I am using AAAA record.

Answer (score 0):

> GitHub Pages currently does not support IPv6

Check again if this error persists today, considering that (Sept. 2021):

> ### Enabling IPv6 Support for GitHub Pages
>
> GitHub Pages now supports IPv6 for all Pages hosted on `*.github.io` and custom domains.
>
> Documentation for enabling IPv6 with custom domains [can be found here](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site).